# What does this line of C/C++ preprocessor mean?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, preprocessor

This is Line 519 of `WinNT.h` (BUILD Version: 0091)

```
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name
```

Why do we need a pointer to an struct with a single int member with a weird name called `unused`?

And will we ever need to use a line of code like this one?

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = new HINSTANCE__;
```

Overall declaring different data types with the same structures, doesn't make sense to me. What's the idea behind this?

```
DECLARE_HANDLE(HRGN);
DECLARE_HANDLE(HRSRC);
DECLARE_HANDLE(HSPRITE);
DECLARE_HANDLE(HLSURF);
DECLARE_HANDLE(HSTR);
DECLARE_HANDLE(HTASK);
DECLARE_HANDLE(HWINSTA);
DECLARE_HANDLE(HKL);
```

Answer (score 15):

The point is for the different handles to have different types so that, for example, a HINSTANCE isn't assignable to a HANDLE. If they were all defined as "void*", then there are classes of errors that the compiler could not detect.

Comment: So, the idea behind it is to have integer data types which will not be used for purposes other than what they were declared for?

Comment: Yes, that provides type safety for handle types so you get an error when you try to pass a HINSTANCE to a function that requires a HANDLE even though the underlying structure is identical.  (This answer was going to be just "yes", but that evidently wasn't verbose enough. Extra verbosity added.)

Comment: ahhh I see why C doesn't allow anonymous structs as parameters to functions now; if it treated anonymous structs as equal to any identically struct with same setup, it would make C not cause errors to make this trick work. That said, I'm pretty sure allowing it would allow for more flexible code, but at least there's a reason. it also seems to indicate that there is real code reliance on pointers being exactly size of int, otherwise handle would break and a lot of code would need to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

> And will we ever need to use a line of code like this one?
>   HINSTANCE hInstance = new HINSTANCE__;

You usually use a `HINSTANCE` value returned by a Windows system call; I have never seen code executing a line like that.

Answer (score 1):

They don't actually point to anything to memory; they are just used to refer to objects (files, resource, semaphores, windows) when making calls to the Windows API. While they're nothing more than just indexes into kernel's object tables, the developers decided that they make it a pointer to an unused structure which would make them "opaque" and cause less confusion between other types. The `DECLARE_HANDLE` is a function macro that does just that - declaring opaque types for handles.